# arm cross compilation unrecognized --sysroot option.(Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, arm, cross-compiling, ld

I'm trying arm cross compilation using `sysroot` for the `autotools` project.The options I'm using for `autogen` script is as follows.

```
CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --with-sysroot=/opt/sysroot/dir \
   --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --sysroot=/opt/sysroot/dir --prefix=/some/dir
```

But in eclipse plugin it is showing that `--sysroot` option is unrecognized but the same command is working fine in the terminal.

```
ERROR:
configure: error: unrecognized option: --sysroot=/opt/sysroot/dir
configure: error: unrecognized option: --sysroot=/opt/sysroot/dir
Try ./configure --help' for more information
```

And If I remove `--sysroot` option in eclipse then the `autogen` works fine but I'm getting the following linker error.

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libwebkit_clutter-0.so when searching for -lwebkit_clutter-0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libwebkit_clutter-0.so when searching for -lwebkit_clutter-0
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/workspace/Sharukh/sources/applications'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lwebkit_clutter-0
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/workspace/Sharukh/sources'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libwebkit_clutter_mx.so when searching for -lwebkit_clutter_mx
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libwebkit_clutter_mx.so when searching for -lwebkit_clutter_mx
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lwebkit_clutter_mx
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libcgroup.so when searching for -lcgroup
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //lib/libcgroup.so when searching for -lcgroup
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcgroup
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin_Sharukh] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your target Linux distribution? Have you looked at [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/)? It even has an Eclipse [plug-in](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#_integration_with_eclipse).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't need to use `--with-sysroot` as `--sysroot` is enough.

Your configuration should be like this

```
CC="arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" \
CFLAGS="--sysroot=/opt/sysroot/dir" ./configure \
            --prefix=/some/dir \
            --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

Comment: @Sushant: Yeah thanks sushanth.I had done the same thing and it's working fine but I forgot to update it here.Thanks again,Upvoted :)